# Getting multicast messages with UDPClient

Tags: c#

I've got a product plugged directly into the ethernet port of my computer, sending multicast packets to 224.224.10.10 and UDP port 24588. I've set up my UDPclient in the code below, and I feel like I have it set up correctly, but I still don't receive any packets. I always catch an exception saying that I timed out waiting for a response. Any thoughts or glaring mistakes?

I looked at a lot of questions before posting this, but I couldn't get a resolution, and I couldn't find anyone who had the same type of setup that I have.

```
public class ReceiverClass
{
    private UdpClient m_UDPClient = null;
    private Thread m_UDPReceiverThread = null;
    private bool m_ContinueReceiving = false;
    private readonly object m_sync = new object();
    private const int UDP_PORT = 24588;

    public ReceiverClass()
    {
        m_ContinueReceiving = true;
        m_UDPClient = new UdpClient(UDP_PORT);
        m_UDPClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 20000;

        m_UDPReceiverThread = new Thread(ReceiveData) { IsBackground = true };
        m_UDPReceiverThread.Start();
    }

    private void ReceiveData()
    {
        bool Continue;
        byte[] ReceiveBuffer;
        IPEndPoint defaultIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        m_UDPClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("224.224.10.10")); 
        m_UDPClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

        lock (m_sync)
        {
            Continue = m_ContinueReceiving;
        }

        while (Continue)
        {
            try
            {
                ReceiveBuffer = m_UDPClient.Receive(ref defaultIP);

                if (null != ReceiveBuffer)
                {
                    // Do stuff with received...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ooo eee kill stream
                Dispose(false);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                lock (m_sync)
                {
                    Continue = m_ContinueReceiving;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was going to the Sockets class and looking at the raw packets and picking out what I needed. I bind the socket to my lan interface, and sniff stuff out. I had to run it as an administrator in order to get it to work, but thats fine. I went this route because I could see the packets in wireshark, but they weren't getting to my udpclient. This ended up being the fastest way to get what I wanted.

```
        Socket ReceiveSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
        EndPoint DefaultIPEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.2.0"), 0);

        ReceiveSocket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
        ReceiveSocket.Bind(DefaultIPEndpoint);
        ReceiveSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, null);

        while (true)
        {
            byte[] ReceiveBuffer = new byte[512];
            int ByteCount = 0;

            ByteCount = ReceiveSocket.ReceiveFrom(ReceiveBuffer, ref DefaultIPEndpoint);
            // Handle packets ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything immediately wrong with your code so I don't have a proper answer for you. However, here's a piece of code I'm using to get UDP broadcast messages. Hopefully it will work for you, or give you some new ideas:

```
class UdpHandler {

    public UdpHandler(int portNo) {
        Thread t = new Thread(ListenThread);
        t.IsBackground = true;
        t.Start(portNo);
    }

    public void ListenThread(object portNo) {
        UdpClient client = new UdpClient { ExclusiveAddressUse = false };
        IPEndPoint localEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, (int)port);
        client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        client.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        client.Client.Bind(localEp);

        while (true) {
            byte[] data = client.Receive(ref localEp);
            DataReceived(data);
        }
    }

    private void DataReceived(byte[] rawData) {
        // Handle the received data
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it didn't help me. Theres a difference in the setup between broadcast and multicast messages I think, but I don't know what. Still stuck. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.